# Problems in modifying and adding extension to firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I downloaded an extension from firefox renamed the xpi to zip and unpacked it. Then repacked the same folder using "zip" to create the xpi(sounds silly but i am planning on making modifications to the code, though i have not done in this case), howerver when i add that extension back to firefox, firefox is reporting the extension might be corrupt. I am running firefox in Mac OS X.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess the error message is "This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt". That message appears for signed extensions if they have been modified - the very purpose of a signature is to prevent unauthorized modifications. You should remove `META-INF` directory before packing the extension back, that directory contains the signature. The extension will show up as unsigned then but I don't think you care.

Comment: This is the command i use to zip. Am i rite in doing so?

zip -r plugin.xpi pluginDirectory/*

Comment: @Julius: No, it isn't - all names in your ZIP file will start with `pluginDirectory/`. Do `cd pluginDirectory/` first and then `zip -r ../plugin.xpi *`.